# How do you return values greater than a certain value from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My goal for this is to return all of the outliers in both the upper and lower range of the dataframe based on the 1.5 IQR.  I'm aiming to do that with the use of the "for" loop in the iqrmult function.  When I remove the loop, the output prints the correct upper and lower value but I'm unsure of how to print the values greater or lower than it.  The csv file looks as posted below, but with 1000 rows total.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('seaborn')
#question 2

s = pd.read_csv('NormalSample.csv')


def iqrmult(s, subset):
    
    q1 = s[s.group == subset]['x'].quantile(q=.25)
    q3 = s[s.group == subset]['x'].quantile(q=.75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    iqrmultiplier = iqr * 1.5
    
    lower_range = q1 - iqrmultiplier
    higher_range = q3 + iqrmultiplier
    
    count = 0
    for x in s:
        if s[s.x >= higher_range]:
            count = count + 1
    print('IQR is ', iqr)
    print('25% IQR is ', lower_range)
    print('75% IQR is ', higher_range)
    #print('The lower outliers are ', outlier1)
    print('The upper outliers are ', count)
    

iqrmult(s, 0)
```

| group | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 324 |
| 0 | 102 |
| 0 | 237 |
| 1 | 290 |

Answer (score 0):

Note that `s[s.x >= higher_range]` yields a **DataFrame** (rows meeting
your condition), not a single value, so you can not use it as a boolean
expression.
You will get *ValueError* exception.

To count elements in a **whole** array, meeting your condition,
you can use *Numpy*:

```
count = np.count_nonzero(s >= higher_range)
```

Actually, under the hood, *s* is converted to the underlying *Numpy*
array, which then is used as the argument to *count_nonzero*.

But if you are interested only in a **single column**, you can generate
a boolean *Series* - whether each element meets your condition and then
just sum *TRUE* values (*TRUE* is counted as *1* and *FALSE* as *0*):

```
count = (s.x >= higher_range).sum()
```

But I noticed that you want to return **all of the outliers**, not
the number of them.
To get the actual **values**, you can run:

```
outliers = s.x[s.x.between(lower_range, higher_range)]
```

The result is a *Series*, so the index column presents
additionally **indices** of rows meeting your condition.

Or to get both outliers **separately**, run:

```
lower_outliers = s.x[s.x <= lower_range]
upper_outliers = s.x[s.x >= higher_range]
```